# Why url query string doesn't pass a variable value?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I am trying to pass a parameter in query string i.e.`_type=1` but it doesn't pass. It doesn't appear in URL, other values does but not this one. Why ?

```
 SitePaymentReportByBranch = function () {
          $('#btnprintSitePaymentByBranch').on('click', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if ($("#form1").validationEngine('validate')) {
                  var _employerID = "";
                  if ($('#cmbEmployerSitPaymentByParameter :selected').text() == "-Select-") {
                      alert('Plz Select Employer');
                  }
                  var url = '/Reports/frmSitePayment.aspx?_EmployerID=' + $('#cmbEmployerSitPaymentByParameter :selected').val() + '&_Formdate=' + $("#formdate").val() + '&_Todate=' + $("#todate").val() +'_type=1';
                  commonStartup.openReportWindow(url);

              }
          });

      },
```

Comment: You forgot the last `&`, and you should URLencode those values

Comment: & is missing. Never happens in real coding as no sane person builds urls with string concatenation - they write helper method once and use it everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters must be separated with `&`. You have omitted this for your `_type` parameter:

```
'_type=1'
```

should be;

```
'&_type=1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `&` before `_type` fix will be `'&_type=1'`

```
var url = '/Reports/frmSitePayment.aspx?_EmployerID=' + $('#cmbEmployerSitPaymentByParameter :selected').val() + '&_Formdate=' + $("#formdate").val() + '&_Todate=' + $("#todate").val() +'&_type=1';
```